# MyBatis - SpringBoot maps results to wrong objects

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to do a multi-table select. Below is my mapper.xml:

```
<select id="getPublicationById"
        resultMap="publication"
        parameterType="string" useCache="false">
    SELECT p.pubId,
           p.pubTitle,
           p.pubBody,
           p.pubDate,
           p.pubAuthor,
           p.articleType,
           si.imageId as imageId, # imageId is a foreign key referenced in p
           si.imageUrl as imageUrl,
           sv.videoId as videoId, # videoId is a foreign key referenced in p
           sv.videoUrl as videoUrl,
           sa.attachmentId as attachmentId, # attachmentId is a foreign key reference in p
           sa.attachmentUrl as attachmentUrl
    FROM publication p
             LEFT JOIN site_image si ON p.thumbnailId = si.imageId
             LEFT JOIN site_attachment sa on p.attachmentId = sa.attachmentId
             LEFT JOIN site_video sv on p.videoId = sv.videoId
    WHERE p.pubId = '${pubId}'
</select>

<resultMap id="publication"
           type="PubModel">
    <constructor>
        <idArg column="pubId" javaType="String"/>
    </constructor>
    <result property="pubId" column="pubId"/>
    <result property="pubTitle" column="pubTitle"/>
    <result property="pubBody" column="pubBody"/>
    <result property="pubDate" column="pubDate"/>
    <result property="pubAuthor" column="pubAuthor"/>
    <result property="articleType" column="articleType"/>
    <collection property="thumbnail" ofType="SiteImage">
        <id property="imageId" column="imageId"/>
        <result property="imageUrl" column="imageUrl"/>
    </collection>
    <collection property="video" ofType="SiteVideo">
        <id property="videoId" column="videoId"/>
        <result property="videoUrl" column="videoUrl"/>
    </collection>
    <collection property="attachment" ofType="SiteAttachment">
        <id property="attachmentId" column="attachmentId"/>
        <result property="attachmentUrl" column="attachmentUrl"/>
    </collection>

</resultMap>
```

The particular row I am querying have null foreign keys for `videoId` and `attachmentId`, therefore, I am expecting the returned `SiteVideo` and `SiteAttachment` objects to be null.

However, it looks like MyBatis is assigning irrelevant results to these two objects:

```
PubModel(pubId=spongebob101, pubTitle=spongebob, pubBody=haha, pubDate=2021-08-30T15:10:38, pubAuthor=Wang Cai, articleType=MARKDOWN, thumbnail=[SiteImage(imageId=1, imageUrl=google.com)], video=[SiteVideo(videoId=spongebob101, videoUrl=spongebob)], attachment=[SiteAttachment(attachmentId=spongebob101, attachmentUrl=spongebob)])
```

As you can see, the fields assigned to both of the objects are actually the result of `pubId` and `pubTitle` which are not expected. What is going on here?

I have tried other methods like using association instead of collection, and not using neither of these. But nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the [related PR](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/2276) I have found the solution to my problem. I added all-arg constructors to my POJOs, Java automatically got rid of the no-arg constructors. It looks like when the no-arg constructor is non-existent MyBatis automatically switches to constructor auto-mapping. Constructor auto-mapping relies on the column order of the returned result and MyBatis just had to call the all-arg constructors of my POJOs with some non-null results.

The solution is to manually add another no-arg constructor then MyBatis no longer uses constructor auto-mapping.